# Cannot bind CascadingParameter from parent component to child component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a parent component as this

```
<CascadingValue Value="@_data">
    <Virtualize Items="@Items" Context="option">
       <ChildComponent Text="@option.Text"></ChildComponent>
    </Virtualize>
</CascadingValue>

@code{
    private DataClass _data;
    private event EventHandler<ChangeEventArgs> ChangeEvent;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _data = new DataClass("name", ChangeEvent);
    }
}
```

and child component

```
@code{
    [CascadingParameter] protected DataClass CascadedData { get; set; }
}
```

CascadedData property not bind by CascadingParameter from parent component and is null .What is the problem?

Note : I checked parent component without Virtualize component, same result.

Comment: The code as you show it should work.  Make sure the parent `OnInitializedAsync` is getting called.  If so then there's something happening in the code in the parent or child you haven't shown us.

Comment: Post a __minimal__ mre ([mre]) without the Virtualize and without the event. Because it should work already,

Comment: Use public instead of protected...

Comment: @enet  I started typing your comment, but went away and tested it before posting.  It works with both a private property/field in the parent and the `CascadingParameter` declared as private.

Comment: Instead of dumping the full project on us, create a [mre]. Start with a standard template and post all the changes. But it will show you the problem isn't where you think it is.